# Why do I get an 1004 error when adjusting conditional formatting from within an error handling sub?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling

So, I'm trying to insulate my excel sheet from an error messing with the rest of the macros because I lost all my variable definitions.

So, I have an initialize subroutine that was running on workbook open.  I defined it as a sub in module and now call the sub on workbook open.  I also call the sub in my error handling routine.  Here's the module code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Fixed As Range
Public Motor As Range
Public Engine As Range
Public Stage1 As Range
Public Stage2 As Range
Public Stage3 As Range
Public Drive As Range
Public Stage As Range
Public Required As Range
Public SaveChk As Integer
Public SaveName As String
Public UserPath As String
Public Path As String
Public SaveError As Integer
Public EditChk As String
Public FormRange As Range

Sub Initialize()

'Set all of the cell check and formatting ranges
Set Module1.FormRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Service Report") _
    .Range("A1:AL59")
Set Module1.Fixed = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Service Report") _
    .Range("I7,I8,Z7,E6,P6,X6,A45,A57,F57,L57,P57,V56,V57,X57,D28,D29,O28")
Set Module1.Motor = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Service Report") _
    .Range("AA28,AA29,Z30,AE30,AC31,AJ29,AK30,AK31")
Set Module1.Engine = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Service Report") _
    .Range("D15,M15,T15,AE15,AJ15,T17,AE17,AH17,J23,J24,J25,AA20,AA21,AA22,AA23,AA24,AA25,AJ20,AJ21,AJ22,AJ23,AJ24,AJ25")
Set Module1.Stage1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Service Report") _
    .Range("H37,N37,AA37,AG37,AG38,H38,K38,N38,Q38,AA38,AD38,AJ38")
Set Module1.Stage2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Service Report") _
    .Range("H39,N39,AA39,AG39,AG40,H40,K40,N40,Q40,AA39,AA40,AD40,AJ40")
Set Module1.Stage3 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Service Report") _
    .Range("H41,N41,AA41,AG41,H42,N42,Q42,AA42,AG42,AJ42")

'Disabling Drag and Drop for Unprotected Cells
Application.CellDragAndDrop = False

'Set the start parameters of the worksheet
Module1.EditChk = "N"   'Set to Y to allow saving when not complete (debugging), Set to N for standard'
Module1.SaveChk = 0
Module1.SaveError = 0
Module1.FormRange.FormatConditions.Delete
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Service Report")
    .Range("A1:AL59") _
        .ColumnWidth = 2
    .PageSetup.PrintArea = "A1:AL59"
End With
Sheet1.CheckBox26.Value = True
Sheet1.CheckBox18.Value = False
With Module1.Motor.FormatConditions _
    .Add(Type:=xlBlanksCondition)
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    .StopIfTrue = True
End With
Sheet1.Shapes("Option Button 134").ControlFormat.Value = xlOn
Module1.Stage2.FormatConditions _
    .Delete
Module1.Stage3.FormatConditions _
    .Delete
With Module1.Stage1.FormatConditions _
    .Add(Type:=xlBlanksCondition)
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    .StopIfTrue = True
End With
Set Module1.Stage = Module1.Stage1
Module1.Fixed.FormatConditions.Delete
With Module1.Fixed.FormatConditions _
    .Add(Type:=xlBlanksCondition)
    .Interior.Color = vbRed
    .StopIfTrue = True
End With

End Sub
```

I'm also capturing paste commands and converting them to paste special values.  When a user tries to paste from one merged cell to a different sized merged cell there is the typical Excel error.  When the initialize routine runs from my error handle, halfway through it 1004 errors on:

`ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Service Report").Range("A1:AL59").FormatConditions.Delete`

If I remove that line it errors on the next conditional formatting command.  To sum it up: No Errors on workbook open, but a 1004 error on sub call during error handling.

EH code

```
Private Sub Workbook_SheetChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)

'Error Handling when workbook is unprotected so it doesn't lose it's protection on an error.
On Error GoTo eh

Dim lastAction As String

'Get the last action performed by user
lastAction = Application.CommandBars("Standard").Controls("&Undo").List(1)

'Check if the last action was a paste
If Left(lastAction, 5) = "Paste" Then
    'Without disabling events, the undone command will redo right after undo
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Undo
    Target.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

Exit Sub

eh:
'Renables protection on error.
Call Initialize
Application.EnableEvents = True
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Field Service Report").Protect Password:="x", UserInterfaceOnly:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you show us the error handling where you're calling `Initialize`?

Comment: So, after messing around, it definitely has something to do with the fact that its in a subroutine define in a module.  If I copy the offending code into the workbook open sub it works fine.

Comment: So what line now errors and what is the error? 463 and 9, or just 9?

Comment: Sorry, had to reset everything and rerun.  So...when the initialize is called from Workbook open.  No issues.  When initialize is called from workbook_sheetchange I still get a 1004 runtime error on the edited line Module1.FormRange.FormatConditions.Delete

Comment: If you're handling an error, you won't lose your Global variables.  That would happen on an *unhandled* error.

Comment: Well, all I know is that I get the same error on my range union because one or more ranges is null unless I did that on error.  So, that's an old fix.  Maybe I'm not "handling" my errors appropriately.